# Examples to use netflix-feign outside of spring-boot

Tags: spring-mvc, netflix-eureka, netflix-feign

I m looking for a example how to use netflix-feign from a NO-spring-boot app.
I have a existing SpringMVC (4.2) webapp. Now i build some "microservices" with Spring-boot + (eureka, feign) and i want to use those as backend serivces from the webapp.

thanks in advance

Comment: Here is an pure example of Feign: http://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/07/18/java-rest-client-using-netflix-feign/

Answer (score 3):

In the github repo you can see a few examples to use `feign-client`:

- https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign

Basically, you would need to create an interface annotated with `feign` annotations and not with the `Spring`, one example would be (you can see much more in the github page):

```
public interface YourClient {

     @RequestLine("POST /")
     @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
     Response getSomething(@Param("id") String id);

}
```

Then to instantiate your feign client it's need to use its builder `Feign`. It's easy, and configurable:

```
YourClient yourClient = Feign.builder()
                       .decoder(new GsonDecoder()) // you could use Gson, Jackson,...
                       .target(YourClient .class, "https://your.url");
```

Then you can use it just invoking the method you want:

```
yourClient.getSomething("myId");
```